# Sorting files into directories

Tags: c#, file, directory

I have task to sort files into directories.

I have files like:

```
AA12.txt
AA34.txt
AA56.txt
BB12.txt
BB34.txt
etc.
```

**And I need to create a function that wil create directory based on the first two letters and copy the coresponding files there.**
So there will be directory AA with files AA12,AA34,AA56 and directory BB with the files BB12,BB34 etc.

```
AA
 |- AA12
 |- AA34
 |- AA56

BB
 |- BB12
 |- BB34
```

I was thinking about just creating all the directories by hand and then copying the files.

```
string directoryPath = @"C:\\AA";
if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
}
```

But is there more elegant and automated way of doing something like this?
Thanks

Comment: You already said what you want/need to do `And I need to create a function that will create directory based on the first two letters and copy the corresponding files there.`. Where are you getting stuck? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: you don't know how to extract the first 2 letters from the filename? you don't know how to combine a path with the 2 letters to create a full directory path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Mong Zhu for pointing out the full path issue try this:

```
string path = ".";
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    string dirfileName = fileName.Substring(0, 2);
    if (!Directory.Exists(dirfileName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirfileName);
    }

    File.Copy(path + "\\" + fileName, path + "\\" +dirfileName + "\\" + fileName);
}
```

Comment: a little more explanation of what this piece of code does would greatly improve the quality of your answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sohaib Jundi I came to the solution and I did it this way:

```
string path = @"C:\\";
string destination = @"E:\\";
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            string onlyFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            string dirName = onlyFileName.Substring(0, 2);
            string dirPath = $@"{destination}\{dirName}";
            if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
            }

            File.Copy(fileName, $@"{dirPath}\{onlyFileName}");
        }
```

Thanks Sohaib Jundi for you help and hopefuly somebody will find this useful.

Comment: this : `if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))` is actually superfluous. `CreateDirectory` will only create if the directory does **not** exist yet. Otherwise it will do nothing

Comment: why do you extract the filename `Path.GetFileName(fileName)` twice?

Comment: I have edited the GetFileName so it only extract once now.

Comment: if the answer by @SohaibJundi helped you to solve the problem. You should mark it as accepted. If you don't know how to do it, [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might help.